# In Android RecyclerView, dynamic sorting of Items based on number of clicks

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am implementing RecyclerView with Cardview. I want to dynamically sort the cards based on number of clicks. For example, If i click card at position 4 two times then it will move to position 1.

Comment: Could you be more explicit about what have you tried so far and with what part of the task do you have problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can add an integer variable to the object in the array list and use it for counting the click.
Every time the user click you can sort the list by the new variable and call notifydatasetchange() to notify the adapter that the list order is change! I can be more specific if you provide some code!

Comment: I have already written code for Recyclerview with cardview thats working fine. Due to some reason i can't share code. I would appreciate if you provide example code. Any online link related to this. Because I have seen apps implement this but I don't found any code online.